# sync functions node.js with postgresql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, asynchronous

I have some problemos with managing the async funciontions. Here is my code:

```
    var query = client.query("select * from usuario");

    query.on('row', function(user) {
    var queryInterest = client.query("select interes.nombre from interes inner join relacioniu on relacioniu.idinteres=interes.id where relacioniu.idusuario = '"+user.id+"'");
    queryInterest.on('row',function(row) {
            user.interest = row;
            console.log("user added");
        });
    users.push(user);
    });
// After all data is returned, close connection and return results
    query.on('end', function() {
        done();
        console.log("finish");
        return res.json(users);
    });
```

The users array push an user before the execution of queryInterest, so the user's interests are never added. How can I solve this?

Thank you so much

Comment: why can't you move `users.push(user);` inside `queryInterest.on`. this will solve your problem.

Comment: In that case the return of the code is an empy array

Comment: Yes because your end event is on `query` object. so as soon as the query completes it return the object. you can consider using `async` library.

Comment: Check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), it is easier to use ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = client.query("select * from usuario");

query.on('row', function(user) {
var queryInterest = client.query("select interes.nombre from interes inner join relacioniu on relacioniu.idinteres=interes.id where relacioniu.idusuario = '"+user.id+"'");
queryInterest.on('row',function(row) {
        user.interest = row;
        users.push(user); // Moved it here; this is async, too.
    });
});
```

Comment: the exit with your modification is: Starting child process with 'node ./bin/www'
finish
GET /api/v1/tander 200 28.330 ms - 2
user added
user added
 So the return of the code is now empy